# How to make different paths [array of paths] routes to same Component with children path

Tags: angular

Below is the my AppRoutingModule things.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'basicSearch', component: BasicSearchComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'type' },
      { path: 'code', component: BasicSearchCodeComponent,
        children: [
          { path: ':codeId', component: CodeDetailsPopupComponent },
        ]
      },
      { path: 'code/:ssnNo', component: BasicSearchCodeComponent,
        children: [
          { path: ':codeId', component: CodeDetailsPopupComponent },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'basicSearch' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

Whenever user hits "http://abc/basicSearch/code" and "http://abc/basicSearch/code/R1234" need to routes to "BasicSearchCodeComponent", here I'm reading whether routed urls has query/path parameters.

When user click on a button in BasicSearchCodeComponent page, we need to show an popup of "CodeDetailsPopupComponent" and here I'm reading whether routed urls has query/path parameters, for this urls will be "http://abc/basicSearch/code/10001" and "http://abc/basicSearch/code/R1234/10001".

But its not working as per required, because when user click on button instead of showing popup, application getting reloaded to BasicSearch component.

Could you please suggest me whether I'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: What is it that that is not working at the moment? Any error messages?

Comment: When I click on button with url "http://abc/basicSearch/code/10001" and "http://abc/basicSearch/code/R=1234/10001", it suppose to open the popup over the BasicSearch Result page. instead of it, its reloading into the BasicSearch page

Comment: Try to put together a stackblitz demo of your setup. It seems to me there are some router-outlet's missing in your parent routes (or, maybe, some parent routes shouldn't be exactly parent routes, just more specific routes).